# Какая лучшая реализация получения значения "последнего" класса?

Tags: java

Схематично структура проекта такая:

```
class Main -> class A -> class B -> class C
```

Класс `A`:

```
class A {
    private ArrayList<B> bs = new ArrayList()<>;

    public ArrayList<b> getB(){
        return bs;
    }
}
```

Класс `B`:

```
class B {
    private ArrayList<C> cs = new ArrayList()<>;

    public ArrayList<C> getC(){
        return cs;
    }
}
```

Класс `С`:

```
class C {
    private int value;
    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

В классе `Main` необходимо получить сумму всех значений переменных `value` из класса `С`.

Класс `Main`:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A aClass = new A();

        for(int i = 0; i < aClass.getB.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < aClass.getB().get(i).getC().size(); j++){
                value += aClass.getB().get(i).getC().get(j).getValue();
        }
    }
```

Каким образом лучше это реализовать? Считается ли нормальной реализацией способ, который использован в коде выше - путем получения целого `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, как мне видится, тут в любом случае придется перебирать оба списка, однако сделать это можно элегантнее:

Допустим, с помощью foreach:

```
for(B bClass : aClass.getB) {
    for(C cClass : bClass.getC) {
        value += cClass.getValue();
    }
}
```